# Bouncing divs in their own place?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a simple bouncing effect for my divs. The bouncing effect works in a way but I don't get why the divs go under each-other when they bounce which is not what I want. I need the divs to bounce in their own place.

This is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4tpkugbm/)

And this is the my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".balls").effect('bounce', { times: 3 }, 'slow');
});
```

The bouncing effect kicks in on page load. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the library is adding a containing `div` element around each `.balls` element which is by default `display: block`, hence each element is pushed to it's own line. When the animation ends this element is removed and they return to sitting on the same line. To fix this you just need to add this rule to your CSS:

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4tpkugbm/4/)

Comment: Hey, I think that it is very nice answer but I see a little issue here since it will affect **every animated object** - am I right? [Take a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uds6dhpv/2/)

Comment: That's right, but the animated elements should be grouped within their own container, so the CSS selector can be amended to target the correct elements.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
    float:left;
```

instead of

```
    display:inline-block;
```

[check out the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tpkugbm/3/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add

```
display:inline
```

to the `divs` which are supposed to bounce,check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uds6dhpv/)

Answer (score 1):

The effect plugin wrapping your div within div having class .ui-effects-wrapper and adding inline float none into the div. Use below css and playing with top css property. You need to use below css :

```
.ui-effects-wrapper{float:left!important;}
```